# Xml parsing XPathExpressionException

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
public static ArrayList<Article> parse(InputSource input) {
        ArrayList<Article> result = new ArrayList<Article>();

        try {

            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(EXPR_LIST, input, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(EXPR_LIST, input, XPathConstants.NODESET);
...
```

in **nodes2** line I get error

```
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: java.io.IOException: InputStreamReader is closed
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by *after nodes2 line*? You get an error in a specific line and you withhold that line from us? What happens where the dots are?

Comment: I get error in `NodeList nodes2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(EXPR_LIST, input, XPathConstants.NODESET);` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you evaluate an XPath expression on a stream, you must read the stream first. Once the stream is read, there's nothing to read from it again on the second line.

Rather than trying to read the same stream multiple times, you should parse it once into a DOM structure and then apply expressions on the DOM structure.

For instance:

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers.xpath;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

public class XPathTest {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL sampleURL = new URL("http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/simple.xml");
            Document document = parse(sampleURL);

            List list = document.selectNodes("//food/name");

            System.out.println("Following food items found from the menu:");
            printList(list);

            list = document.selectNodes("//food/price");

            System.out.println("Let's check out some prices:");
            printList(list);

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Couldn't read document...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops! URL was malformed...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static void printList(List list) {
        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Node node = (Node) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(node.getText());
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    private static Document parse(URL sampleURL) throws DocumentException {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        reader.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return reader.read(sampleURL);
    }
}
```